# Images don't show up after VS 2012 Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, webdeploy

I have created asp.net web project. I have included some files in this project. Following all CSS standards required.

```
background-image: url('~/Images/sideheader.png')
```

I can see all pictures when I debug my site. But when I publish my site, I don't see any picture in my site.

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the images are in the correct directory in the publish location?

Comment: yes. 100 times :P , otherwise, it wouldn't have shown up during debug.

Comment: Debug usually launches a server instance specific to the debug project. If this is being published to a different server, the directory referred to by your relative URL may not be the same directory.

Comment: @MikePrecup, Then how do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Manually copy sideheader.png into the ~/Images/ directory on whatever server you're publishing to. I can't really help more than that, since it would require knowledge of your server setup.

Comment: Pictures are copied to Images folder on server during publish. Thats not the issue.

Comment: Have you checked your server configuration to see what the home directory is?

Comment: @MikePrecup, how do we do that?

Comment: Well, first, check if that's the problem. Try setting the ~/Images/sideheader.png url to an absolute path instead of a relative one.

Comment: it shows up when I put images in root folder. I can see images. But if I put it in the folder. I cannot see it then...

Comment: Then what you need to fix is your URL. ~/Images/sideheader.png doesn't resolve to the address you think it does. I can't tell you what to set it to, because I don't know how your server is configured. If you can, the easiest way to do it is to replace the URL with a direct link to the image. If you need to use a relative URL, you'll need to figure out either was ~ is referencing, or use other relative URL options, like / and ../.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30190/discussion-between-mike-precup-and-jasim-khan-afridi)

Answer (score 1):

When you manually add files (i.e. images/js/css) to a directory and use them directly in your html/css (as per your question) Visual Studio does not know they exist. You need to 'show all files'  and then 'include in project' the images/files you want to publish.

Only the files which are visible (=included) in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio will be published to your server.

[image]

Comment: The OP stated in the comments that 'Pictures are copied to Images folder on server during publish.' It looks more like a path resolution issue, since she is using relative URLs.

Comment: OP stated that when debugging he sees the images. This is a local VS instance, referring to the local files on disk. This has nothing to do with publishing. Publishing (Via Visual Studio) only copies the files included in the project to the remote server.

Comment: I guess i found the solution http://www.geospecialling.com/index.php/2009/04/using-relative-urls-in-css-with-aspnet/

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like this :

```
background-image: url('/Images/sideheader.png')
```

in this way the relative paths resolves to the correct place .

Answer (score 0):

Your URL isn't pointing to the file. It works fine on the debug server, because when you run it in debug, it starts up a testing server for your project that has a different configuration than the server you published to. Because you have it in a different directory, or have a different home directory configured, it can't find the image.

For anyone coming to this question, this was determined from testing if replacing the relative URL with an absolute one would solve the problem, which took place in the comment section of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your folder `images` to your project and republish your project. To add the folder, go to `solution explorer`, click on `show all files`, right click on your `images` folder and select `include in project`. You don't need to change any urls of the images you have used in your css or any where else.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, in my case since the Images folder is not recognized by Visual Studio, I had to set read permissions to everyone.  Once I set the Image folder permissions, my images showed up just fine.